# Maven resources filtering doesn't copy non-filtered files

Tags: java, maven

I have xml file that contains properties which must be substituted with specific values. So I use resources filtering to achieve this.

Here is resources structure:

> ```
> src
>    - main
>       - java
>       - resources
>          - VAADIN
>             -themes
>          - UI.gwt.xml
>       - webapp
>          - WEB-INF
> ```

Resources filtering usage in pom.xml:

> ```
> <resources>
>     <resource>
>         <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
>         <filtering>false</filtering>
>         <includes>
>             <include>**/VAADIN/themes/*</include>
>         </includes>
>         <excludes>
>             <exclude>**/UI.gwt.xml</exclude>
>         </excludes>
>     </resource>
>     <resource>
>         <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
>         <filtering>true</filtering>
>         <includes>
>             <include>**/UI.gwt.xml</include>
>         </includes>
>         <excludes>
>             <exclude>**/VAADIN/themes/*</exclude>
>         </excludes>
>     </resource>
> </resources>
> ```

As a result of `clean install`, I receive .war file with UI.gwt.xml with replaced properties but without VAADIN/themes folder and its content. If I comment `<resources>` then VAADIN/themes appears in .war file, but UI.gwt.xml is without specific values.

What is wrong with my filtering configuration?

Comment: In the directory structure shown, I see VAADIN.themes, however in the config we have VAADIN/themes in both resources.  Is that a typo in the question?  If not, that's likely the issue.

Comment: @user944849, It doesn't matter whether I use VAADIN/themes or VAADIN.themes. It is how package chain without content in between in my IDE is shown. But I recheck it anyway.

Comment: @user944849, Rechecked with VAADIN.themes - it still doesn't work. So I edited resources structure not to confuse others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When defining resources on the same `directory` you can specify the files to have filtering applied using `includes` on the resource where `<filtering>true</filtering>`, while where `<filtering>false</filtering>` you specify the files not to be altered using `excludes`. Thus your example will become:

```
<resources>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>true</filtering>
        <includes>
            <!-- whatever is defined here will have filters applied -->
            <include>**/UI.gwt.xml</include>
        </includes>
    </resource>
    <resource>
        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/resources</directory>
        <filtering>false</filtering>
        <!-- everything in this directory remains the same (no filters) -->
        <excludes>
            <!-- the excludes found here will be altered by the filters in the first resource set -->
            <!-- so we need to define them as excluded from the files that should not have filters applied -->
            <exclude>**/UI.gwt.xml</exclude>
        </excludes>
    </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what order I use. It still doesn't copy VAADIN themes :(

Comment: I was now reading the warning at the last example on this link http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html it seems that the filtering applies to the included files and on the second rule it tells it what to do with the ones that are not filtered. Try removing the excludes from the filtered resource

Comment: Yes, I reversed the order of filtering (first filter and then w/o filter) and removed include with VAADIN themes. Thus everything worked as I wanted. But I still cannot understand why it behaves in such a way :(